# How to quotient the free group by a set of elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, formal-languages, quotient-spaces, context-free-grammar, free-groups

Let $F =$ the free group generated by $\Sigma \cup V$ where $\Sigma = \Sigma(s)$ is the minimal alphabet that $s$ is over, and $V = \{V_1, \dots, V_n\}$ is a finite set of variables.

I would like to quotient by the smallest normal subgroup containing all of $V_i^{-1} v_i$ where $v_i = $ a substring of $s$ or basically a string over $\Sigma$.  We've essentially then identified all variables with what they will be expanded to in the course of working out various grammars that generate $\{s\}$.

How would we take the smallest normal subgroup containing all those elements?

Comment: I switched from free monoid over to free group and perhaps things will work more nicely.

Comment: Do you have one such relation for each $i$? And are you more interested in the quotient or in the normal closure of your relators?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier yes for each $i$ and am more interested working in the quotient.

Comment: Well then, it couldn't be simpler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you've identified *all* variables $V_i$ with strings in the alphabet $\Sigma$. The quotient by the normal closure of this set of relators is going to be naturally isomorphic with the free group over $\Sigma$, no more and no less.

Usually when you quotient a free group, what you are doing is basically writing down a presentation for your quotient. No one ever wonders what the normal closure of the set of relators looks like, but if this is really what you want, you can say that it is the set of all finite products of conjugates of your relators and their inverses:

$$\bigcup_{m=0}^\infty\left\{\prod_{i=1}^m g_iR_ig_i^{-1}, g_i\in F, R_i\in\mathfrak{R}\right\}$$
with $\mathfrak{R}=\left\{V_1^{-1}v_1,v_1^{-1}V_1,\ldots, V_n^{-1}v_n,v_n^{-1}V_n\right\}$.

Comment: Is there an obvious way to write down the normal closure such as:
  $\{ y z^k y^{-1} : z \in \text{some finite set}, k = -K, ..., 0, ... K, y \in F \}$?

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond I've edited the answer to include a symbolic version. For each $m$ you have the set of all products of $m$ conjugates of relators or inverse of relators.

Comment: If $x, y$ in your set then $x = \prod_{i=1..m} g_i R g_i^{-1}$, $y = \prod_{i=1..k} h_i R' h_i^{-1}$, then their product is $xy =\prod g_i R g_i^{-1} \prod h_i R' h_i^{-1}$ which is not necessarily of the right form (take $R \neq R'$), so I think your formula can be corrected and probably simplified.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond I simply forgot the $_i$ under the $R$ :) fixed, sorry about that. Corrected, yes (thanks) - simplified, I very much doubt it (you're in a free group, there are no relations to allow you to simplify things).